# Collect/Expand with D

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I am new to MMA and have a basic question. 
I am trying to separate the derivatives of an expression for simplification. 
E.g. on doing

```
D[OverBar[u][x, y, z, t], x] + a*D[OverBar[u][x, y, z, t], {x, 2}]
```

outputs

$a \bar{u}^{(2,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)+\bar{u}^{(1,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)$

And when I do

```
D[OverBar[u][x, y, z, t] + a*D[OverBar[u][x, y, z, t], x], x]
```

it again outputs the same - i.e. it combines the two separate instances of `D`.

$a \bar{u}^{(2,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)+\bar{u}^{(1,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)$

I would like to prevent that since in my work I can replace `OverBar[u][x, y, z, t] + a*D[OverBar[u][x, y, z, t], x]` with say A and simplify to `D[A, x]`.

What function would be used for that? Expand?

**The goal is ----**

when I have an expression in the form of

$a \bar{u}^{(2,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)+\bar{u}^{(1,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)$

**Can I separate the derivatives? Say using Collect or some MMA function?**
that would give me an output of the form

$D[a \bar{u}^{(1,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)+\bar{u}(x,y,z,t),x]$

because by assuming 
$A = a \bar{u}^{(1,0,0,0)}(x,y,z,t)+\bar{u}(x,y,z,t)$

I can get simplified expression as D[A,x]

TIA

---

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the tour and how to write in formatted form.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't have blank in my inputs, it came up when I copied the output from MMA to posting the question. But I will get rid of OverBar in my future codes. Here the issue is not that though, I just tried running without OverBar and I still run into same issue.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The title of your question, for instance, is "Collect/Expand with D", but you are using neither `Collect` nor `Expand` in your code.  And, what is it specifically that you wish to prevent?

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is in the last 5 lines of my question (also written in the 2nd line) which can be said as the part 2. I added part 1 (first 8-10 lines) since it was related to my problem. I do not have to use Collect or Expand if there is a better function in MMA. I am new to MMA so based on what I learnt, I thought Collect or Expand might be used.

Comment: I changed the last few lines of the question - should be clearer now?

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent the outermost D from actually taking the derivative, right?  What do you want to do with the expression next

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm trying to derive an expression where in some terms if I do not take the 2nd derivative, it can be replaced with another expression say A.